# Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) using double backslash to separate paragraphs

Tags: paragraphs

I am quite new to LaTex. I separate each of my paragraphs with a double backslash (\\). However, for every paragraph I do so, I get the following error:

**Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph**

Can I ignore this error? Or is there an alternative/better way to use \\?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you end your paragraphs with ``\\`` in the first place? In general ``\\`` should never be used in the running text.

Comment: @daleif Seems to become a meditation phrase: '`\\ ` should never be used in running text', '`\\ ` should never be used in running text', '`\\ ` should never be used in running text', , ... ommmmmm

Comment: @gernot use double backpings at each end   The ``\\`` overuse seems to come in waves

Comment: @daleif Thx for the hint with the double backticks. It seems some people start into LaTeX without reading any tutorial first (which I basically understand: who cares for the docs?)

Comment: @gernot back in the day I wrote my Danish LaTeX book for the same reason. At that time most people learned only from the "not so short guide" and attempted to solve every typesetting issue only using what ever was in that pamphlet. But it also come from bad quality YT videos and Overleaf templates. I think the raise in `\Large{....}` we have seen comes from a wrong setting in the Overleaf interface.

Comment: using `\\ ` at the end of a paragarph is always wrong and will generate that warning. It does not add vertical space it adds a new (empty) line of text  at the end of the paragraph.

Comment: if you want vertical space between paragraphs use for example `\usepackage{parskip}`